# Help and Advice in Regards to Smoothing out a Sculpted Model

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Recently started teaching myself Blender and 3D modeling. I have a background in Graphic Design, and feel like my real strength is a program like Illustrator where it's easy to draw with geometric shapes!

Been working on this cute mouse as a way to get my head around all things blender. Now the base of the head was made with two spheres being merged together and the boolean tool to better merge them together.

But whilst working throughout Blender and sculpting; I'm noticing some weird "wrinkles" on the surface of my sculpts. Attached are screenshots circulating and highlighting some of these spots. I've tried using the "smooth" and "flat" sculpting tools and changing the intensity and size of the brush but they still seem to be lingering around. As an illustrator buff, I'm all about smooth surfaces and clean geometry so that's the real challenge I'm finding with Blender

Might be a basic and obvious question but would love to be pointed in the right direction as to how I can fix this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need more detail on the model... Are you using Dynotopo? if not, try to watch some tutorials about that

Comment: I don't think more geometry is needed, that is a problem with shading and normals. In general and long run it's best to familiarize yourself with topology and way to control it. For that model, [edit] the question with the screenshot of the model in Edit mode so that edges are visible. I guess some cleanup is required after boolean; ideally you want all your edge loops go along model contours (when possible)

Comment: Not possible to determine without seeing the wireframe, but my guess is not enough geometry just as @Emir mentioned. Long triangles make bad shading.
You can also look into these modifiers: 'Normal Edit' & 'Weighted Normals'

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone!

@MrZak One thing I've been struggling with Blender is how "organic" a lot of the shapes become after using the Sculpting Tools so I'm quite eager to find a Workflow that's more conducive to working with geometric shapes and offer a bit more precision and control. Will definitely need to familiarise myself with more topology as I guess that's a barrier to entry for my sculpting at the moment!

Comment: @fourtwo I've just uploaded some of the wireframes and I can see how poorly skewed the lines are. Are there any references for a better work flow to get these types of shapes but without sculpting brushes so there's more control over the geometry and shapes of the plains? 

The ears were done with sculpting tools and clearly the topology of the basis of the face wasn't aligned too well which has caused the triangles on the side.

Comment: @Chai-Time, You can see it in this image, https://ibb.co/KDDpVDt
how adding loopcuts can help reduce the normal issues

Comment: If that model is for sculpting then more geometry will be needed (like if you want to add tiny details on the surface) but that will require retopology, one way is remesh. So far those meshes are easier to model and shade without sculpting tools. One example of controling topology is shown above, more general guides are here https://topologyguides.com/ or in tutorials on organic and character modeling / sculpting, like ones on YT by Grant Abbitt or YanSculpts etc

Comment: Hey Guys, just wanted to send a huge thank you for your comments and help! I went through a tutorial binge and learnt more about: mesh density, sculpting with dynotopo, subdivision modifiers and it's all pointed me in the right direction to refine what I needed to and get a better workflow. 

Don't know if you're interested but I found a youtube tutorial that has a similar basis to the characters I want to model and going to digest it all so I can see a better way to form my workflow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkOk8UAux8s&t=58s

Can't thank everyone enough!